# how to declare 10^9 size array in java

Tags: java, arrays

The following error is being shown:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

when I declare:

```
long[] ar = new long[1000000000];
```

So how to declare an array which size is 10^9?

Comment: I think the answer is, don't try and declare a ludicrously big array requiring more memory than you have available. Whatever you think you need it for, probably find another way to do it.

Comment: This sounds like an [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/286538). You should probably [edit] the question and explain what the actual problem you are trying to solve is.

Comment: What's the purpose of creating an array of that size, especially with longs. That just makes everything worse.

Answer (score 0):

To create an array of one billion 8 bytes `long` values you need at least 8 GB of free memory in the old generation.  I suggest giving the heap at least 12 GB, if you have enough memory start with 32 GB.

if you don't have this much memory, you can use a memory mapped file on Linux, but most likely there is a more memory efficient way to store the data (depending on why you are trying to do this)